# selectize.addOption is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

Here is my js code. I need add option to previously declared selectize object

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var tso = $('.assign-tags').selectize();
        console.log(tso);
        tso.addOption({value:100, text: 'BBBBB'});
        tso.refreshOptions();
        tso.addItem(100);

    });


</script>
```

log prints object data but then  getting

```
tso.addOption is not a function
```

What do i do wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_options  You may have to do `tso.options.addOption`

Comment: now tso.options is undefined

Comment: Ok, without making a [mcve] of the issue and digging into it I'm not sure then.  The documentation is slightly less than clear, :(

Comment: ok you docs helped. Thanks. Found answer there :)

Comment: So nice to not publish the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it with jQuery is a simple `append`:

```js
var tso = $('#assign-tags');
tso.append('<option value="100">BBBBB</option>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="assign-tags">
  <option>Select an option</option>
</select>
```